# Manually upgraded QEMU 3.1 does not support qxl video device

Tags: graphics, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I want to use the latest version of QEMU (3.1) with my installation of Ubuntu Server 18.04.2. I have managed to install it, but it seems that the new installation is not correctly connected to all the dependencies (or perhaps I need to manually upgrade other packages to get them in sync with my upgraded QEMU?)

the error I got was:

```
ERROR    unsupported configuration: this QEMU does not support 'qxl' video device
Removing disk 'WINVM.img'                                   |    0 B  00:00     
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start myWINVM
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

Do my suspicions about the cause of the problem seem reasonable? What should I try to get QXL working again (it was working before the QEMU upgrade).

Comment: You're on the cutting edge!  The [documentation for 3.1.50](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html)  indicates that it does support qxl, but it's unclear which version you are running.  You could try being on the bleeding edge by compiling from the git source.  Another alternative would be to load Ubuntu 19.04, which uses qemu 3.1 - but I think that this has more to do with development versions of the programs...

Comment: I am using 3.1.0, which I downloaded and compiled from here: https://download.qemu.org/qemu-3.1.0.tar.xz

Comment: The [webpage for qemu](https://www.qemu.org/download/#source) has instructions for downloading the very latest development version, downloading and building from git.

Comment: OK that didn't work, I think next I will step back to 3.0 and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error after building QEMU from sources. It needs every dependency already installed in the system when calling "./configure" because this is the step that detects system capabilities. If you compile QEMU and then install dependencies like spice, qxl, etc it won't detect them later and you need to recompile.